# Does host file overrides DNS for SQLConnection?

Tags: .net, vb.net

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts overrides DNS for MSDOS.  For example, if you have the correct IP address in DNS and the incorrect IP address in the host file, then you will not be able to ping the domain name on the PC containing the host file.

Does this same principle work for the SQLConnection object? For example, please see the code below:

```
Dim objCon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
```

Will the web server connect to data source: server if the host name contains an invalid IP address for: server.

Comment: I've not found a situation yet where changing the hosts file doesn't affect connectivity, I doubt a connection string is any different.  However, why not just try it and see?

Comment: @James Thorpe, I have tested it.  It appears that ASP.NET ignores what is in the host file.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that MS DOS has its own TCP/IP settings in Windows. The hosts file configures local name resolution for the TCP/IP stack in Windows. I.e. it affects SQL connections as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the hosts file overrides anything that uses name resolution, including the SQL client (which uses standard DNS resolution).

*UPDATE*

If you don't present a [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (as you did not in your sample), then depending on the operating system(s) and the network configuration involved it may fall back to NetBIOS name resolution.  This is an old broadcast related method of resolving host names to IP addresses (it's like screaming "Hey BOB!" in your office and waiting for Bob to respond to you).  I wouldn't lean on this, but it can explain why it still seems to work when you put an invalid name in the hosts file.

Comment: If you specify "dsn=connectionName", will it still use the hosts file?

Comment: I have entered an invalid IP address into the host file.  MSDOS fails to resolve the IP address, however the web application can still connect to the database?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath It would use the hosts file / DNS to locate whatever server is specified in that connection string.

Comment: I have tested it. It appears that ASP.NET ignores what is in the host file

Comment: @w0051977 See my update, are you trying to accomplish something specifically, or are you just asking so you can understand what is happening?

Comment: @CodingGorilla,I am trying to prevent a web server from connecting to one specific database (it connects to thirty databases).

Comment: @w0051977 You might want to try this instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445(v=sql.120).aspx  If you're trying to force the machine to generate an error while connecting to a specific database, you could just create a broken alias.

Comment: @ CodingGorilla, I have disabled NetBIOS on the web server and it now works i.e. it respects the hosts file.  Thanks.